# cant find iPhone simulator in application support

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to add photos to my iPhone 6.0 simulator but i cant find the folder in the Application Support. Not the iPad simulator either. Can it be somewhere else or do I have to download something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

finder -> go -> go to folder -> paste exactly the following:

```
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/
```

you can place your photos here.

:)

Comment: it says "folder cant be found" ? :(

Comment: I have found the 4.3.1 iphone simulator but it is not the one i use

Comment: Are you sure you are using 6.0 simulator?

Comment: Yes i am but it may be because i drag the iPhone simulator folder to an extern harddrive some months ago to save memory and when a moved it back it still just had the 4.3.1 version.

Comment: This could be the issue... check the portable hard drive and search for the folder

Comment: it says folder cant be found:(